# Check for variable changes after some time

Tags: java, android, tcp

In my project i have a **TCP Server** that make a sound a vibrate after a **TCP Client** send a package to it, but now i want that if the counter from the **TCP Server** is **!= 0 after 60 seconds** repeat the sound and vibration but i don't know how to implement that ***IF*** function that controll if the counter is changed after 60 seconds.
Probably there is a simple solution but i'm new in android.

Here is my **Server.java** *code*:

```
public class Server {
DataBaseHandler myDB;
allert Allert;
MainActivity activity;
RecyclerViewAdapter adapterView;
Adapter adapter;
ServerSocket serverSocket;
public static int count=0;
String letto = "";
private SharedPreferences prefs;
static final int socketServerPORT = 8080;

public Server(MainActivity activity) {
    this.activity = activity;
    Thread socketServerThread = new Thread(new SocketServerThread());
    socketServerThread.start();
}

public int getPort() {
    return socketServerPORT;
}


public void onDestroy() {
    if (serverSocket != null) try {
        serverSocket.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}


private class SocketServerThread extends Thread {
    Vibrator vibrator;
    String date,ora;
    long[] pattern = {0, 1000, 500, 1000, 500, 1000};

    int lun;

    @Override
    public void run() {
        InputStream leggi;
        try {


            serverSocket = new ServerSocket(socketServerPORT);

            while (true) {
                myDB = DataBaseHandler.getInstance(activity);

                Socket socket = serverSocket.accept();
                leggi = socket.getInputStream();
                byte[] data = new byte[1000];
                lun = leggi.read(data, 0, data.length);
                letto = new String(data, "UTF-8");
                count++;
                MediaPlayer mPlay = MediaPlayer.create(activity, R.raw.gabsuono);
                mPlay.start();

                vibrator = (Vibrator) activity.getSystemService(VIBRATOR_SERVICE);
                vibrator.vibrate(pattern, -1);

                date = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy").format(new Date());
                ora = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss").format(new Date());
                myDB.insertDataServer(date, ora, letto);








                        activity.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {

                        allert.refreshing.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        prefs = activity.getSharedPreferences("MY_DATA", MODE_PRIVATE);
                        SharedPreferences.Editor edit = prefs.edit();
                        edit.putInt("counter", count);
                        edit.commit();
                        MainActivity.msg.setText(String.valueOf(count));
                        MainActivity.msg.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                    }
                });
                leggi.close();


            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();

        }

    }


}

public void Parti() {
    prefs = activity.getSharedPreferences("MY_DATA", MODE_PRIVATE);
    count = prefs.getInt("counter", count);
    MainActivity.msg.setText("" + count);
    if (count == 0)
        MainActivity.msg.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    else
        MainActivity.msg.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);


    }

}
```

Comment: which variable is the one you want to check after 60 secs? Is it `count`?

Comment: i want to check the count variable

Comment: do you want to check every 60 secs or just one time after 60 secs?

Comment: I want to check it every 60 seconds

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `Handler#postDelayed` this code..

```
final Handler handler = new Handler();
    handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
      @Override
      public void run() {

        //Check something after 60 seconds

        handler.postDelayed(this, 60000); //1000ms = 1seconds * 60
      }
    }, 1); // first trigger 1ms. change this if you want to starts at 60 sec make it 60000
```

Hope it helps..

Comment: Actually this works fine in MainActivity but at the first start it's vibrate before 60 seconds and after it it works fine...

Comment: you can edit 1 to 60000 on the last line of code if you want it to trigger on first 60 seconds. .  see comment on edit :)

Answer (score 1):

Just get the date when you first vibrated, store it, and when the counter is !=0 , get the date again, and then calculate the distance between the two times. If it's > 60 seconds, vibrate, update the first date. Repeat the algorithm.

demo in a simplified version of your code:

```
long date1 = -1;
while(true){    
    if(date1!= -1 && counter!=0){
        long date2 = System.currentTimeInMillis();
        if(date2-date1>60000){//60 seconds
          vibrateAgain();
          date1 = date2; //don't forget to update the date

        }        
     }

//your code ...
vibrateFirstTime();
date1 = System.currentTimeInMillis();
}
```

Comment: Mh probably there is some issues because after 60 seconds nothing heppens, maybe i have to do this code in MainActivity?